# Is there a way to print simple roots as Root objects?

Tags: equation-solving, front-end, boxes

I like the typesetting of Root objects. For example:

```
3-Sqrt[2]+Sqrt[3]//RootReduce
```

But can I get the same root object with its typesetting for simple roots like follows?

```
3-Sqrt[2]//RootReduce
```

Comment: By "typesetting" do you mean the 2D boxes (as shown in Bob's answer), or a `Root[…]` expression as shown in Akku14's answer?

Comment: @xzczd 2D boxes as shown in Bob's answer for now. Since I want to quickly see the numerical value of the roots that are appearing in my code but still keep them as exact quantities. But if there is a way to get the `Root` expression to print like that without automatically turning into explicit roots that is even better.

Comment: It would sometimes be nice to represent quadratic roots as `Root` objects to avoid numerical instability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
expr = 3 - Sqrt[2];
```

Use [`ToNumberField`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToNumberField.html) to convert the expression to an [`AlgebraicNumber`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AlgebraicNumber.html)

```
expr2 = expr // ToNumberField
```

[image]

The short form display of the `AlgebraicNumber` is similar to that of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html)

[`RootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html) will convert the expression back to the radical representation.

```
expr2 // RootReduce

(* 3 - Sqrt[2] *)
```

Comment: Nice idea, but this does'nt answer the question "
I like the typesetting of Root objects"

Answer (score 5):

You can discover the polynomial with [`MinimalPolynomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinimalPolynomial.html):

```
p = MinimalPolynomial[3 - Sqrt[2]]
(*    7 - 6 #1 + #1^2 &    *)

p[x]
(*    7 - 6 x + x^2    *)

Root[p, 1]
(*    3 - Sqrt[2]    *)
```

From the documentation of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html):

> For linear and quadratic polynomials `f[x]`, `Root[f,k]` is automatically reduced to explicit rational or radical form.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it from reducing to explicit form? I want the nice typesetting. Also is there a way to know in advance which root number of the `MinimalPolynomial` the root is?

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it from reducing to explicit form? No, according to the quoted documentation. Is there a way to know in advance which root number? You may have to look at both roots and see which one fits.

Comment: `3-Sqrt[2] // ToNumberField` will provide an `AlgebraicNumber` with short form display similar to `Root`. `RootReduce` will convert the `AlgebraicNumber` back to the radical representation.

Comment: @BobHanlon that looks like the perfect solution! Please write it as a solution so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap HoldForm only around Root.

**Edit**

```
p = MinimalPolynomial[ro = 3 - Sqrt[2]];

a = Select[Range[10], Root[p, #] == ro &][[1]] // Quiet;

hf = HoldForm[Root][p, a]

(*   Root(#1^2-6 #1+7&,1)   *)

hf // ReleaseHold

(*   3 - Sqrt[2]   *)
```